# Off a bulk and now cutting

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, food, fat, bellyfat

So I just finished a bulk phase and I'm entering a cutting program. I've been losing weight so far, but my question is does it really matter if I don't reach my calorie deficit target? It's at 2700 calories, but I only reach about 2000 calories.

My protein intake is very high at about 210 grams, but my carbs is lower than what those calculators tell me I should be eating. Does it really matter to reach that carb amount? I mean I understand I need energy but I dont have any energy problems in the gym. As a matter of fact I've been increasing weight. New lifter gains but still, I'm really confused.

Those calculators give me such a high protein and carb level that I have to make. As long as I keep my protein and fat right its ok? I dont have to follow carbs that much?

Comment: 210 grams of protein is staggering. I've always wondered how people get there. I'm guessing ~80 in some form of powder and the rest in the form of eggs/chicken/beef?

Comment: Actually i had it all in the form of chicken..about 800gs if chicken a day..but ill prob drop down tho..i jus wanted to keep it high at first cuz i trained hard n was scared to lose muscle on the cut

Comment: That's dedication, I'll say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to your body. As long as your energy level is staying high and you're hitting your workouts, then you're fine. Fewer carbs/calories will mean faster results.

The key here is to keep listening to your body - you may feel energetic on those 2000 calories during the first week, but if that deficit starts to catch up with you and your energy levels decrease as you continue to cut, then increase the carbs until you can function well. Keep testing, keep adjusting.